TextField hiding behind keyboard JetPack Compose
I'm just starting to learn Compose, so basically I'm trying to make a notes application. I'm facing an issue with the text field.
In the create or edit screen, there is a text field that takes up the whole screen except for the title and app bar. When I try to type more in the text field, it hides behind the keyboard.
In normal Android XML view edit text, it will push previous lines above the current line.
But with the text field, the current line is pushed down behind the keyboard.
Have tried this :
https://medium.com/@mark.frelih_9464/how-to-handle-automatic-content-resizing-when-keyboard-is-visible-in-jetpack-compose-1c76e0e17c57
